# Reference Monitor Vs. System Call Wrapper

Tags: reference, system, call, wrapper, monitor

I am trying to clearly distinguish both terms/techniques  according to their properties and uses.
I am mostly interested in the difference between them.

I know that they work the same way by interposing system calls. Or I might be  wrong!

However, I am still confused about for example what layer and mode ( user, kernel) the System Wrapper belongs to as well as to what layer and mode the Reference Monitor belongs.

With as few words as possible.
Please tell me anything you know about those two interposition techniques.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpret the two:

**System Call Wrapper**
A system call wrapper is code in user mode that wraps system calls.  That is, it gets executed before and/or after a system call to verify certain properties.  A simplistic example of this would be adding a layer of code around execve to check permissions or record this action.  As is, libc and other libraries already wrap system calls.  You don't usually directly use execve, clone, open, read, or write - instead there are versions like execv, fork, fopen, fread, and fread to make the programmer's job a little easier.

**Reference Monitor**
On the other hand, I think a reference monitor serves a somewhat different function.  It tries to mediate access to resources and this can be done in both user and kernel and can interpose on system calls or even lower.

I think the best way to distinguish the two is that one (system call wrapper) is an implementation, whereas the other (reference monitor) is an idea or policy you would like to enforce.  That is, you could wrap system calls in a program to ensure access control and proper resource allocation, but the idea and the implementation are not one and the same.

Note: I'm not very familiar with reference monitors. I used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_monitor and http://www.cse.psu.edu/~tjaeger/cse544-s10/papers/refmon.pdf as partial sources.